# Section styles in asp.net webpages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have the code below to add the scripts to a content page controlled by a layout page, it works. However i'm looking to do the same for css styles. I've searched, but to no avail. What I got was the "@section style" syntax which didn't work. I've seen it in mvc, but i'm not sure if it works in webpages. Can someone please let me know how this could be archived...if possible. Thanks in advance!

```html
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [razor view: insert <style> in body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401242/razor-view-insert-style-in-body)

Comment: Why does it need to be in the section? Why can't you include the stylesheet in the <head>?

Comment: So can I use head on a page linked to a layout page?